# Can a DTO have instance format data methods?

Tags: java, methods, format, instance, dto

My question is : can a DTO have instance format data methods ?

For instance:

```
public class CosasDTO{

  String cosa_nombre;
  String cosa_apellido;
  String cosa_fecha;


   ///-------------------------Constructor

    public CosasDTO(CosaExtrema cExtrema) {

        cosa_nombre = cExtrema.getName();
        cosa_apellido = cExtrema.getApellido();
        cosa_fecha = formatDate(cExtrema.getDate());
    }

    private String formatDate(Timestamp fechaHora) {

    String horaFechaFormateadas = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(fechaHora);

        return horaFechaFormateadas;
    }
}
```

Is it correct to instantiate a formatting method within the DTO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting/Localization is the responsibility of the presentation (endpoint) layer so in general no. While persistence you save the date/time in UTC and format it in the presentation layer based on the user's preference.

Comment: Im using the DTO to write a File..is for an database extraction. The final point is the File.  is correct in this case?..... Thank you!

Comment: Then the data extraction should not interact with the DTO directly. It should do so by using a facade or a service that does the conversion for you. You should always use layering approach while building solutions

Comment: CosaExtrema is a DAO object. Then I will format the date using a service rather than directly.        .......... Thank you!

Comment: @user1794285 accept this as the answer if I've correctly answered your question